# updateApplicationContext - stacked context's?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos, watchconnectivity

I have an issue with applicationContext in Watch Connectivity. 
I Use updateApplicationContext on the iOS side to update a state which is handled by the Watch.

The docs state "This method replaces the previous dictionary that was set, so you should use this method to communicate state changes or to deliver data that is updated frequently anyway."

However, If updateApplicationContext is called several times, with different dicts, they seem to stack?

When I open the Watch App after being suspended for a while, didReceiveApplicationContext is called several times with historical contexts, so not only the latest.

I was under the impression that in these situations only the latest context update will be delivered to the Apple Watch. Am I mistaken?

Comment: If you are referring to https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/713/ he states that updateApplicationContext is only a single set. Does not mention that they are stacked. Also the Docs says "This method replaces the previous dictionary that was set"

Comment: yes messages and transferUSerInfo are stacked. applicationContext should not, but is!

Comment: I am also noticing this behavior. Were you ever able to figure out what was happening?